# How to redirect output of top command in a file

Tags: unix, freebsd

for monitoring purpose of system, i need to redirect the output of top command in a file so i will use/parse it.
i am trying to do same thing but CPU performance stats are not getting saved in a file see
screen shots.
expected output:

```
[root@v100 /usr/local/bin]# top
last pid:  6959;  load averages:  0.01,  0.03,  0.03                                                                                   up 0+02:47:34  17:51:16
114 processes: 1 running, 108 sleeping, 5 zombie
CPU:  0.0% user,  0.0% nice,  1.6% system,  0.0% interrupt, 98.4% idle
Mem: 734M Active, 515M Inact, 226M Wired, 212M Buf, 491M Free
Swap: 4095M Total, 4095M Free

 PID USERNAME  THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE    TIME   WCPU COMMAND
 1953 root      150  20    0  3084M   635M uwait    2:44  0.00% java
 1663 mysql      46  20    0   400M   139M sbwait   1:29  0.00% mysqld
 1354 root       31  20    0 94020K 50796K uwait    0:24  0.00% beam
 4233 root        1  20    0   122M 23940K select   0:06  0.00% python
 1700 zabbix      1  20    0 20096K  2436K nanslp   0:03  0.00% zabbix_agentd
 1799 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  7240K nanslp   0:02  0.00% zabbix_server
 4222 root        1  30    0   122M 23300K select   0:02  0.00% python
 1696 zabbix      1  20    0 19968K  2424K nanslp   0:02  0.00% zabbix_agentd
 2853 root        1  20    0   126M 29780K select   0:02  0.00% python
 1793 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  7152K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
 1797 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  8348K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
 1752 root        1  20    0   122M 22344K select   0:01  0.00% python
 1796 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  8136K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
 1795 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  8208K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
 1801 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  7100K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
 3392 root        1  20    0   122M 23392K select   0:01  0.00% python
 1798 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  7860K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
 2812 root        1  20    0   134M 25184K select   0:01  0.00% python
 1791 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  7188K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
 1827 root        1 -52   r0 14368K  1400K nanslp   0:01  0.00% watchdogd
 1790 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  7164K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
 1778 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  8608K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
 1780 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  8608K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
 2928 root        1  20    0   122M 23272K select   0:01  0.00% python
 2960 root        1  20    0   116M 22288K select   0:01  0.00% python
 1776 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  7248K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
 2892 root        1  20    0   122M 22648K select   0:01  0.00% python
 1789 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  7128K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
 1814 root        1  20    0   216M 15796K select   0:01  0.00% httpd
 1779 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  8608K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
 1783 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  8608K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
 1800 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  7124K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
 1782 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  8608K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
 1781 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  8608K nanslp   0:00  0.00% zabbix_server
 1792 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  7172K nanslp   0:00  0.00% zabbix_server
 2259 root        2  20    0 48088K  4112K uwait    0:00  0.00% cb_heuristics
```

If i do:

```
[root@v100 /usr/local/bin]# top > /tmp/top.output
```

then it shows:

```
[root@v100 /usr/local/bin]# cat /tmp/top.output

 last pid:  7080;  load averages:  0.09,  0.06,  0.03  up 0+02:52:24    17:56:06
 114 processes: 1 running, 108 sleeping, 5 zombie

 Mem: 731M Active, 515M Inact, 219M Wired, 212M Buf, 501M Free
 Swap: 4095M Total, 4095M Free

  PID USERNAME  THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE    TIME   WCPU COMMAND
  1953 root      150  20    0  3084M   633M uwait    2:17  0.00% java
  1663 mysql      46  20    0   400M   136M sbwait   1:08  0.00% mysqld
  1354 root       31  20    0 94020K 49924K uwait    0:18  0.00% beam
  4233 root        1  20    0   122M 23776K select   0:04  0.00% python
  1700 zabbix      1  20    0 20096K  2436K nanslp   0:02  0.00% zabbix_agentd
  1799 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  7240K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
  2853 root        1  20    0   126M 29780K select   0:01  0.00% python
  1696 zabbix      1  20    0 19968K  2424K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_agentd
  4222 root        1  28    0   122M 23264K select   0:01  0.00% python
  1793 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  7152K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
  1752 root        1  20    0   122M 22344K select   0:01  0.00% python
  1797 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  8088K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
  1796 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  7944K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
  1795 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  8044K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
  1801 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  7100K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
  3392 root        1  20    0   122M 23312K select   0:01  0.00% python
  2812 root        1  20    0   134M 25184K select   0:01  0.00% python
  1798 zabbix      1  20    0   103M  7628K nanslp   0:01  0.00% zabbix_server
```

so here, I am able to monitor Memory but not CPU
reason is during redirect output of **top** CPU stats did not update

***How can i capture CPU stats also?***

if you have any suggestion pls tell me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`top -b -n 1` seems to work on my Linux box here (-b: batch mode operation, -n: number of iterations).

**Edit:**

I just tried it on FreeBSD 9.2 which uses the `3.5beta12` version of `top`. It seems it needs at least one additional iteration to get CPU stats. So you might want to use:

```
top -b -d2 -s1 | sed -e '1,/USERNAME/d' | sed -e '1,/^$/d'
```

-b: batch mode, -d2: 2 displays (the first one does not contain CPU stats, second one does), -s1: wait one seconds between displays

The `sed` pipeline removes the first display which does not contain CPU stats (by skipping header and process list).

Comment: Thanks to reply, i tried it but it is still not showing CPU stats,
see output:

[root@v100 /usr/local/bin]# top -b -n 1 > /tmp/top.output

[root@v100 /usr/local/bin]# cat /tmp/top.output

    last pid:  9094;  load averages:  0.04,  0.07,  0.06  up 0+04:31:20    19:35:02

    114 processes: 1 running, 108 sleeping, 5 zombie


    Mem: 735M Active, 514M Inact, 232M Wired, 212M Buf, 483M Free
Swap: 4095M Total, 4095M Free



     PID USERNAME  THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE    TIME   WCPU COMMAND

     1953 root      150  20    0  3084M   635M uwait    3:07  0.00% java

Comment: There seem to be different implementations of top, see http://english.turkcebilgi.com/top+%28Unix%29 section History. For me, `top -v` shows `procps-ng version 3.3.3`. ---
You might want to consider alternative sources like `vmstat` command or the proc file-system's `/proc/stat` (see http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm for an explanation of the output). (It wouldn't be a surprise if your `top` takes the info from `/proc` anyway.)

Comment: `root@v50:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.33 # top -v` shows
`top: version 3.5beta12`

in my FreeBsd system, file /proc/stat is not there.

Comment: #top -b -d2 -s1 | sed -e '1,/USERNAME/d' | sed -e '1,/^$/d' > /tmp/top.out 


is working for me.
Thank you a lot.